# Has a play-in team ever won the NCAA Men's Basketball Championship?

Tags: trivia, basketball, collegiate

Has a play-in team (a team that entered the tournament bracket through the preliminary "First Four" tournament games) ever won the NCAA Men's Basketball Championship?  If not, what are the lowest seeded teams to win?

Comment: Not sure how this is unclear. Could this be found rather easily? Sure. But it clearly asks if a [play-in team](http://sports.stackexchange.com/q/2407) has ever won a championship, and if not, what is the lowest seed to do so (as play-in teams are generally double-digit seeded).

Comment: This [edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/revisions/15566/2) added  on to the original question asked, but I wouldn't say it improved or diminished understanding. Improving understanding would have included defining what a play-in team is.

Comment: Good point, sorry, it was a quick edit with a bad explanation.  My motivation in adding the additional question point was to entice a better answer than a yes/no question.  But you're right, I probably could've done more to help this question be understood by those that don't know college basketball as well.  I was surprised there were no details on the seeding topic already, and it would seem a good place to put together a deepest-performance-by-seed breakdown such that it would cover other possible potential questions in the same vein.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Noted. Although I'm on board with your motivation, we should be careful in editing questions to the point where it becomes almost unrecognizable to the original. A nudge in that direction is more appropriate, so that the OP knows what a [good question](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/613) looks like on Sports SE. That said, I just didn't understand why there were unclear votes on a question that was pretty straightfoward in its original form (though it was barebones), and your edit didn't necessarily help with the "stigma" associated with this question.

Answer (score 3):

> Has a play-in team ever won the NCAA Men's Basketball Championship?

No.

> If not, what [is] the lowest seeded [team] to win?

Villanova is credited as being the lowest-seed to win the NCAA Men's Basketball Championship as an 8 seed in 1985<sub>[(1)](http://www.usatoday.com/story/gameon/2013/04/02/ncaa-tournament-final-four-teams-most-shocking/2047219/)</sub>.

Answer (score 2):

The NCAA tournament expanded to include the play-in teams starting in 2011. Since 2011 tournament the lowest seed to win it all has been a 7 seed (UCONN). To answer the first part of your question, no play-in team has even made it to the championship let alone won it. 

To answer your second part, *"Three 11 seeds have made it to the round of four--LSU in 1986, George Mason in 2006 and VCU in 2011. Throughout the history of the tournament, just 14 teams seeded seventh or worse have made it to the Final Four. The lowest seed to win the tournament and national title was the No. 8 seeded Villanova in 1985"* Source:[LINK HERE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidiP-xjafSAhUH6YMKHe1bD8YQFggwMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.al.com%2Fsports%2Findex.ssf%2F2016%2F03%2Fis_syracuse_the_lowest_seed_ev.html&usg=AFQjCNGIxuTXPXaNV2cfrgoUmD7Sfd8MKA)